# Why is my blitted characted not moving in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, blit

I am making an RPG in Python using Pygame. My first step is to create my main character and let it move. But it isn't. This is my code:

```
import pygame,random
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)
blue = (0,255,0)
green = (0,0,255)

global screen, size, winWidth, winHeight, gameExit, pressed, mainChar, x, y
size = winWidth,winHeight = (1350,668)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("RPG")
gameExit = False
pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
mainChar = pygame.image.load("Main Character.png")
x,y = 655,500

def surroundings():
    stoneTile = pygame.image.load("Stone Tile.png")
    stoneTileSize = stoneTile.get_rect()

def move():
    if pressed[K_LEFT]: x -= 1
    if pressed[K_RIGHT]: x += 1
    if pressed[K_UP]: y -= 1
    if pressed[K_DOWN]: y += 1

def player():
    move()

    screen.fill(black)
    screen.blit(mainChar,(x,y))

while not gameExit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            gameExit = True

    surroundings()
    move()
    player()

    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Please help me and explain why it isn't working, too. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to run that code?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to update your pressed variable in each run

```
while not gameExit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            gameExit = True

    pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    surroundings()
    move()
    player()

    pygame.display.update()
```

The values x and y that you have used within that move function are being treated as a local variable you will have to tell the interpreter that they are global variables

```
def move():
    global x,y
    if pressed[K_LEFT]: x -= 1
    if pressed[K_RIGHT]: x += 1
    if pressed[K_UP]: y -= 1
    if pressed[K_DOWN]: y += 1
```